# How to display a string that is processed with substr correctly

Tags: php, substr

```
    $strlength = 10;
    $strshow = 5;
    $fb_detail="My Live K3besdfsfsfdafasf";
    if (strlen($fb_detail) > $strlength)
        $feedback_detail_str = substr($fb_detail, 0[, $strlength]) . '...';
    else $feedback_detail_str = $fb_detail;
```

I followed the exact format that is supposed to be on the PHP codex [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php), but the result can never generate correctly (it will only show '...', not include the ''). What might be the actual issue?

Comment: Brackets in PHP documentation mean that the parameter is optional, but you shouldn't include them in the actual call itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **`string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )`**

The brackets in the documentation is there to indicate that the parameter is optional. You don't have to include it in your code.

Remove those square brackets and your code should look like:

```
$feedback_detail_str = substr($fb_detail, 0, $strlength) . '...';
```

It's also a good idea to separate `if-else` blocks with curly braces. It makes your code more readable and has many other advantages.

```
$strlength = 10;
$strshow = 5;
$fb_detail="My Live K3besdfsfsfdafasf";

if (strlen($fb_detail) > $strlength) {
    $feedback_detail_str = substr($fb_detail, 0, $strlength) . '...';
} else {
    $feedback_detail_str = $fb_detail;
}

echo $feedback_detail_str;
```

Output:

```
My Live K3...
```

Comment: @Chen: As I've stated in my answer, it's used to indicate an optional parameter. It doesn't need to be included in your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

It would always be good, if you refer to examples after function definition. In case of substr(), its string first and then start(int) and length(int) parameters.

Try this :

```
$strlength = 10;
$strshow = 5;

$fb_detail="My Live K3besdfsfsfdafasf";
if (strlen($fb_detail) > $strlength)
    $feedback_detail_str = substr($fb_detail, 0, $strlength) . '...';
else $feedback_detail_str = $fb_detail;
```

Comment: valid answer, but Amal got more detailed one :) maybe improve it in a different way than his will get you further Thanks!